# Update mapview data in separate view controller

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, gmsmapview

**Note: you don't have to be familiar with Google Maps SDK or Places SDK to answer this question.** Hi I am using a `GMSMapView` on my main `MapViewController` and `GMSPlacesClient` from Places SDK on a child view controller to search and return a list of places.
Like this:

[image: Map Search]

What I want to do is to send send the `mapView`'s camera target coordinates (the center of the map on the screen) to the child view controller. Basically I just want to pass data to the next view controller.

So far, I have this:

In my child view controller:

```
let mapViewController = MapViewController()

 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
         searching = true
       
        
        let target = mapViewController.mapView.camera.target
        
        let northeast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: target.latitude + 0.1, longitude: target.longitude + 0.1)
      let southwest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: target.latitude - 0.1, longitude: target.longitude - 0.1)
       
        
      filter.locationBias = GMSPlaceRectangularLocationOption(northeast, southwest)
        
        GMSPlacesClient.shared().findAutocompletePredictions(fromQuery: searchText, filter: filter, sessionToken: nil, callback: { (result, error) in
            if error == nil && result != nil {
                self.matchingItems = result!
               
            }
        })
        mapSearchTableView.reloadData()
       
        
}
```

and in `MapViewController`

```
 @IBOutlet weak var mapViewView: UIView!
    var mapView = GMSMapView()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        locationManager.delegate = self
        
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
        else {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        
        
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 39.8097343, longitude: -98.5556199, zoom: 3.0)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.frame, camera: camera)
        mapViewView.addSubview(mapView)
        
        
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true

}

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
     
        let location = locations.last

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 13.0)

        self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
        
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work, as when I print the `mapViewController.mapView.camera.target` (or the `mapView`'s center coordinates from the `MapViewController`), in the child view controller it shows up with coordinates of (0,0). I have also tried many other ways, including setting `target` within the `MapViewController` itself, and then calling that `target` from the child view controller, but the child view controller only reads the initialized coordinate for `target`, and not the updated coordinate like I want it to.

So basically, what I'm asking is if there is a way to continually update the `mapView`'s camera position coordinates (target) in the child view controller. Please let me know if you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! All it took was adding a `struct` within the original controller- the `MapViewController` containing the target variable, like this:

```
 struct setTarget {
        static var target = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    }

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        setTarget.target = mapView.camera.target
    }
```

I set the target to the `mapView.camera.target` every time it updated a location, and then from my child view controller, I called `MapViewController.setTarget.target` every time that I needed it.